# How to add class to parent if all children got class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to the closest parent when all children got a class `hide`.
In this case when all child elements witch class `matching-attribute` got also class `hide` it should add class `hide` to the parent `compare-group-row`.

I tried the following but that does not work, because in that case it's adding the `hide` class to all `compare-group-row` elements, even when not all child elements got class `hide`.

And it should only add it to the main parent, because we got a lot of these elements on the page.

```js
$(".compare-group-row .attribute-rows .matching-attribute").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hide'))
    $(this).closest('.compare-group-row').addClass('hide');
  else
    $(this).closest('.compare-group-row').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row " role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row " role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it does not work this way, because you are adding or removing the class on the parent multiple times, based on what the _current_ child has. So the final result only depends on the _last_ child you are looping over. You either need to use a flag that you set accordingly based on the children’s status while you are looping over them, and then show or hide the parent based on that flag _after_ the loop over the children;

Comment: or you make it a little easier, and _count_ how many children there are overall, and how many have that class - and simply base the result on whether those two counts match or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by just checking if length of all children is the same as all children's with class `.hide` also or not. If yes, then add the class to parent, else remove it.

```
$(".compare-group-row").each(function() {
  if($('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute.hide', this).length === $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute', this).length)
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('hide');
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".compare-group-row").each(function() {
  if($('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute.hide', this).length === $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute', this).length)
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.compare-group-row {
  padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px 8px;
}

.compare-group-row.hide {
  background-color:#CCC;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row matching-attribute" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row matching-attribute" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or, you can also do this in a few line using [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method like:

```
$(".compare-group-row").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hide', $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute.hide', this).length === $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute', this).length);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".compare-group-row").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hide', $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute.hide', this).length === $('.attribute-rows .matching-attribute', this).length);
});
```

```css
.compare-group-row {
  padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px 8px;
}

.compare-group-row.hide {
  background-color:#CCC;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="compare-group-row active">
  <div class="flex-table group-row row" role="rowgroup">
    <div class="flex-row frist" role="cell">
      <span class="attribute label">ITEM 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
    <div class="flex-row" role="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute-rows">
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row matching-attribute" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row matching-attribute" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-table attribute-row row  matching-attribute hide" role="rowgroup">
      <div class="flex-row first" role="cell">ITEM 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row">VALUE 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of all children and compare it to all matching hide classes. If the length is the same add the hide class.

```js
$(".parent").each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().length === $(this).find('.hide').length) {
    $(this).addClass('hideAll')
  }
});
```

```css
.hideAll {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hide">This should not be visible</div>
  <div class="hide">This should not be visible</div>  
  <div class="hide">This should not be visible</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hide">This should be visible</div>
  <div>This should be visible</div>  
  <div class="hide">This should be visible</div>
</div>
```